# Weird error on mysql_stmt_execute

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a weird error when trying to execute mysql_stmt_execute.

The flow goes:

1. I get the list of the tables in my database I am connecting. (catalog, schema and name)
2. For every table I'm getting the list of foreign keys, fields and indexes.

Everything goes good until I hit the table named `performance_schema.events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name`.

I get the error: `Identifier name "events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name" is too long`. The weird thing is that the name is not an identifier - it is a parameter to the query and it is less than 64 characters which is the identifier limit.

Below is the relevant code:

```
std::wstring query3 = L"SELECT kcu.column_name, kcu.ordinal_position, kcu.referenced_table_schema, kcu.referenced_table_name, kcu.referenced_column_name, rc.update_rule, rc.delete_rule FROM information_schema.key_column_usage kcu, information_schema.referential_constraints rc WHERE kcu.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name AND kcu.table_catalog = ? AND kcu.table_schema = ? AND kcu.table_name = ?;";
char *catalog_name = row[0] ? row[0] : NULL;
char *schema_name = row[1] ? row[1] : NULL;
char *table_name = row[2] ? row[2] : NULL;
MYSQL_BIND params[3];
unsigned long str_length1, str_length2, str_length3;
str_length1 = strlen( catalog_name ) * 2;
str_length2 = strlen( schema_name ) * 2;
str_length3 = strlen( table_name ) * 2;
str_data1 = new char[str_length1], str_data2 = new char[str_length2], str_data3 = new char[str_length3];
memset( str_data1, '\0', str_length1 );
memset( str_data2, '\0', str_length2 );
memset( str_data3, '\0', str_length3 );
memset( params, 0, sizeof( params ) );
strncpy( str_data1, catalog_name, str_length1 );
strncpy( str_data2, schema_name, str_length2 );
strncpy( str_data3, table_name, str_length3 );
params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
params[0].buffer = (char *) str_data1;
params[0].buffer_length = strlen( str_data1 );
params[0].is_null = 0;
params[0].length = &str_length1;
params[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
params[1].buffer = (char *) str_data2;
params[1].buffer_length = strlen( str_data2 );
params[1].is_null = 0;
params[1].length = &str_length2;
params[2].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
params[2].buffer = (char *) str_data3;
params[2].buffer_length = strlen( str_data3 );
params[2].is_null = 0;
params[2].length = &str_length3;
if( mysql_stmt_bind_param( res1, params ) )
{
std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res1 ) );
errorMsg.push_back( err );
result = 1;
break;
}
else
{
prepare_meta_result = mysql_stmt_result_metadata( res1 );
if( !prepare_meta_result )
{
std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res1 ) );
errorMsg.push_back( err );
result = 1;
break;
}
else
{
if( mysql_stmt_execute( res1 ) )
{
std::wstring err = m_pimpl->m_myconv.from_bytes( mysql_stmt_error( res1 ) );
errorMsg.push_back( err );
result = 1;
break;
}
```

Could someone please shed some light on the error? I can probably try to skip this table but I'd prefer not to.

[EDIT]

```
mysql --version
mysql ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.35, for Linux (x86+64) using Editine wrapper
```

[/EDIT]

Comment: Which part of "the name is too long" is hard to understand?  The name given is 46 bytes long (`events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name`).  The error message says "that is too long".  What is the limit on the length of names in MySQL?  Which version of MySQL are you using?  The 5.7 manual on [Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) does say 64, so you aren't at that limit, but something is unhappy with your choice of name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Version of mySQL added to the question. Also, this is not my choice of name - it is system table: identified by the schema. Moreover it is confusing as it is not an identifier - it is a binding parameter. Nothing in the query references that name.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Seems that the code is indeed OK and the strncpy is OK. I mistakenly read that the allocation was twice the length of the string but the length was still only one length of the string.

<strike>The reason why you see that error is because you are using a string which is not null terminated. This is caused by the fact that `strncpy` does not null-terminate the string if it exceeds the given limit and the limit you use is the actual length of the string:</strike>

```
memset( str_data1, '\0', str_length1 );
strncpy( str_data1, catalog_name, str_length1 );
params[0].buffer_length = strlen( str_data1 );
```

A better way to do this would be to use either [`snprintf(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) that does null terminate the string or by using the [`std::string` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)  that takes a `const char*` and a length as parameters.

Comment: Ticket filed. Ref: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88216&thanks=5&notify=71. I put in the reproducible case. Could you take a look when you have a chance. Unfortunately no one from mySQL community replied after initial response. TIA!

Comment: I'd suggest trying with MariaDB or with an older version of MySQL and see if it happens there as well. This way you'll know more about where the problem might be.